# How to move multiple folders to another directory?

Tags: command-line, mv

How can I move multiple folders into another directory ? For example, I would like to move the folder 000/ 001/ 002/ to train/000/ train/002 train/003. Is there a simple command that I can use like

```
mv --from 000/ 001/ 002/ --to train/000/ train/002 train/003
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I could type whatever was typed in this article again, but here:
https://discuss.devopscube.com/t/how-to-move-mv-multiple-directories-or-files-to-a-folder-at-a-time/100

The basic command is:

> You can do this using -t flag with the mv command.
>
> The syntax would look like the following.
>
> ```
>   mv -t <destination> <src1> <src2> .... <srnN>
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: `mv -t 10 11 12 HW` `mv: illegal option -- t`   is `zsh`

Answer (score 2):

I would suspect:

`mv {001..100}/  train/`

Just replace `100` with your folder range.